# Placing Matrices in Tables

Tags: tables, math-mode

I was curious if it was possible to create a matrix within a table?
for example i wanted to create a 2 column table with left containing text and the right containing a matrix. Could someone tell me the syntax?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The suggested and generalized solution should be as follows. It has been used in my production. And vertical correction has been seriously taken into account for the sake of perfectness.

```
\documentclass[preview,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcolumntype{A}[3]{%
    >{\minipage{\dimexpr#1\linewidth-#2\tabcolsep-#3\arrayrulewidth}\vspace\tabcolsep}%
    c
    <{\vspace\tabcolsep\endminipage}}



\def\correction#1{%
    \abovedisplayshortskip=#1\baselineskip\relax
    \belowdisplayshortskip=#1\baselineskip\relax
    \abovedisplayskip=#1\baselineskip\relax
    \belowdisplayskip=#1\baselineskip\relax
    }

\newcommand*\CL{\tabularnewline\hline}
\newcommand*\One{\[\int_a^b f(x)\,\textrm{d}x = F(b) - F(a)\]}
\newcommand*\Two{\[\lim_{x\to y} \frac{y^2-x^2}{y-x}\]}
\newcommand*\Three{\[\begin{pmatrix} a & b\\ c & d \end{pmatrix}\]}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|>{\centering}A{0.6}{2}{1.5}|>{\correction{-1}\strut}A{0.4}{2}{1.5}<{\strut}|}\hline
 Fundamental Theorem\\ of Calculus  & \One \CL
 Limit Function & \Two \CL
 \tikz \draw (2,1) circle (1) (1,1) -- (2,3) -- (3,0) -- cycle; & \Three \CL
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Feel free to edit my answer if you think I did something that disobeys the best-practice protocols.

Comment: If you want to have a table than can be broken across pages, use `longtable` package instead.

Answer (score 3):

This is quite simple to do, but vertical spacing issues will quickly become a problem.  The following example will work in a pinch, but if you search the site for "math in tables" you will find many questions regarding proper spacing of math inside a tabular environment. (Or see [Marienplatz's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/142730/2693). I've used the `array` package to create a column that is in mathmode.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{$}c<{$}} % centred math column
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{cC}
 This is an identity matrix &
\left(\begin{array}{ccc}1 & 0 & 0 \\0 & 1 & 0 \\0 & 0 & 1\end{array}\right)
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]